# How can I copy a JTable to another JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

One way would be through loop by traversing every single row and copy the contents into the other table. Would there be a better way to do so? Assume the goal is to make a second copy of the original table.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the data to another table? If we know the reason why, maybe we can suggest a better approach.

Comment: I only need to know how. An analogy would be to merge two tables.

Comment: A JTable accepts a model. You don't need to copy the JTable, just pass the Model reference to the other JTable.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell, that is why I asked for clarification of the requirement. Passing the reference won't work for a "merge".

Comment: @Cgraphics, see why exact requirement is important? Andrews suggestion was what I was thinking as well but it will not work for a merge. Again the question is why do you need a merger. Maybe you need to create a Model with all the data and then have two different views of the data by filtering the data in each view. If you truly need a merge then yes, brute force is the only way to go.

Comment: FWIW the [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) supports `getRowsAsList()` and `insertRows()`methods which would allow you do to this easily. But behind the scenes it has looping code. So you should be able to add methods like this to your model.

Comment: @Cgraphics My apologies. I didn't read that as a merge, but rather a copy into an empty table. Either way, you shouldn't be caring about a JTable. You should only care about the data model. Merge the two data models regardless of whether it's in one or two or three JTables and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the table model of first table to the Second table.

Comment: new_table.setModel(previous_table.getModel());